# Please help me to sort out the problem. TypeError: The 'int' object is not iterable - this error occurs to me when calculating. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

The task looks like this:
The input of the algorithm is a natural number N. The algorithm builds a new number R based on it as follows.

1. The sum S1 of all odd digits of the decimal notation of the number N is calculated. If there are no odd digits, the sum of S1 is considered equal to 0.
2. The sum S2 of all digits of the decimal notation of the number N, standing in positions with odd numbers, is calculated. The positions are numbered from left to right, starting from 1.
3. The result R is calculated as the modulus of the difference between S1 and S2.
   For example, N = 4321. The sum of odd digits S1 = 3 + 1 = 4. The sum of digits in positions with odd numbers S2 = 4 + 2 = 6. The result of the algorithm is R = 6 – 4 = 2.
   Specify the smallest number, as a result of processing which according to this algorithm will result in the number 31.

Here is my code:

```
for a in range(100):
    s1 = sum(int(x) for x in a if int(x)%2==1)
    s2 = int(a[0])
    R = abs(s1-s2)
    if R == 31:
        print(a, R)
```

This line of code `moment(s1 = sum(int(x) for x in a if int(x) % 2))` returns an error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong or how do I write a program to find the sum of all odd digits of a number?

Comment: `for a in range(100):` - `a` is an integer here.  `for x in a` - you can't iterate over a single integer.  Maybe instead of `for a in range(100)`, you want `a = list(range(100))`?

Comment: I provided an answer below explainig the error - however, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to write. "the sum of all odd digits of a number" - can you provide some examples and their expected outcomes? For example, for 127, is the answer 9 (sum of 1 and 7), or is it the sum of 1 + 3 + ... + 127 you are after? (i.e. not the "digits", but all the *number* between 0 and the given number?)  Your code seems to compute the number at which the sum of all odd numbers upto that number is exactly 31 greater than 0 (so, the sum would be 31 at that point) - something else altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
for a in range(100):
```

So, on the next line, `a` will be `0` the first time, then on the second iteration it would be `1`, etc. `a` is of type `int`.

The next line:

```
    s1 = sum(int(x) for x in a if int(x) % 2)
```

Since `a` is an `int`, `for x in a` tries to iterate over an integer, but that can't be done. So, you get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>     s1 = sum(int(x) for x in a if int(x) % 2)
```

Your short variable names aren't helping to clarify
the difficulty with this code.
Let's define a temp:

```
     digits = list(map(int, str(a)))
     s1 = sum(d  for d in digits  if d % 2)
     s2 = digits[0]
```

(The `list()` call is not strictly necessary,
but I figured you might find it helpful during debugging.)

Apparently `s1` denotes "first sum".
I have no idea how "second sum" fits into the OP code.
You would be well advised to rename `s2` if you want
folks to usefully collaborate.
It is unclear what the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `31` signifies.

---

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .
It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve
and what the expected output would be.